# Errors ("invalid command") when opening a .sql file

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to open a random .sql file off the internet using the following command:

```
psql -h localhost -d database_name -U postgres < file_name.sql
```

But when I run this command I just get errors like the following:

> invalid command 's

> invalid command 's

> invalid command 'll

> invalid command 'Moving

> invalid command 's

> invalid command "frequently

It just continuously prints out these invalid command error messages. I thought it might be an encoding problem but I confirmed the file is UTF-8 encoded.

Any suggestions on how I can open this file

Comment: `psql` is a command line tool, **not** a SQL command that you can run inside pgAdmin

Comment: *trying to open a random .sql file off the internet*. Sounds like an **extremely bad idea**. Have you not at least examined it as text and understood exactly what it actually does?

Answer (score 2):

To expand and clarify on a_horse_with_no_name's comment - the psql command you are running should be run directly in your shell, not inside pgadmin4.

`youruser@yourmachine:~$ psql -h localhost -d database_name -U postgres < file_name.sql`

That command should load the contents of file_name.sql in to database_name. Once it's complete, you can use pgadmin4 as normal to interact with the database.

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what I meant. I've edited the question. I get this error when I run the command in shell.

Comment: You need to share file_name.sql so we can see what you're trying to pass in.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the file contains tabulator keys, which are expanded if you read redirect standard input to the SQL script.

Try using the `-f` option:

```bash
psql -h localhost -d database_name -U postgres -f file_name.sql
```

Comment: I tried that already but am getting the same error.

Comment: Without seeing the offending SQL statements, hard to answer. I was only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the .sql file was generated through a MySQL dump. I thought it would not matter whether I used PostgreSQL or MySQL but it did. Once I installed MySQL my problem got resolved and I now have a Database ready :)